# Where persistence.xml should be?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to figure out why my Java program returns me "No persistence provider for EntityManager name WroProjectPU"
I'm thinking it's happening because Java can't find persistence.xml file.

I tried to use different configurations, but no one worked.
Currently, the structure of my program is looking like this:

[image]

where selected Main.java file is the file, where I have

```
EntityManagerFactory emf =  
        Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("WroProjectPU");
```

The main folder WroProject is under this absolute location:

```
C:\Users\Szymon\workspace\WroProject
```

Could you tell me where I should put my persistence.xml file? The full absolute path please.

Thanks in advance!

AFTER EDIT:
My persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="WroProjectPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>db.User</class>
    <class>db.Session</class>
    <class>db.Email</class>
    <class>db.File</class>
    <class>db.FilePermission</class>
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/wroproject"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="postgres"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres"/>
</properties>
```

The problem:

```
lis 24, 2014 9:30:31 PM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
lis 24, 2014 9:30:31 PM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
lis 24, 2014 9:30:31 PM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named WroProjectPU
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:61)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at wroproject.Main.main(Main.java:18)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Make sure you're spelling "persistence" correctly in your project; you seem to be using a few different spellings in this question.

Comment: Your persistence.xml contains a persistent unit named **WroProjectPU**? Also can you place the stacktrace?

Comment: your persistence.xml specifies the persistence provider as org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider when it should be org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider. I don't think this is causing your issue, though, unless there are more errors/exception further up the log. Since I don't know your build system, I don't know where in your source tree you should put persistence.xml. In my maven build I include it in src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml and it gets put in the classpath correctly.